# Pass a structure to a constructor

Tags: c++, qt

What am I doing wrong here?
I need to make a second constructor that accepts a structure by value.

note.h

```
class Traymenu;

class Note : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, QWidget *parent = 0);  //Working
    explicit Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, struct prop bla, QWidget *parent = 0); //ERROR forward declaration of "struct prop"
```

note.h (alternativ)

```
class Traymenu;
struct prop;           //ERROR: forward declaration of "struct prop"

class Note : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, QWidget *parent = 0);
    explicit Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, struct prop bla, QWidget *parent = 0); //ERROR forward declaration of "struct prop"
```

note.cpp

```
#include "note.h"    
Note::Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, struct prop bla, QWidget *parent) :  //ERROR: bla has incomplete type
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accepting the structure by value, which requires its full definition to be available at that point (it is required to be a `complete type`). Pass by reference to avoid this:

```
Note(Traymenu*, const prop& bla); // reference to const is almost 
                                  // equivalent to pass by value
```

If the copy is really desired, include the definition of `prop`.

You will still need to include the definition of `prop` in the implementation file, if you are doing any operation on the type that requires it to be complete.

Omit the `struct` keyword in variable declarations, it is not required in C++ and I would consider it bad style.

Comment: The `struct` keyword can be used to forward declare in place

Comment: @Paranaix Yes, there it is necessary, but not when accepting the parameter.

Comment: I declare my `struct prop` as a public member variable in another class that calls the `Note`constructor. Hm. It can't be by reference because the struct is immediately changed after the call of the constructor

Comment: @user2366975 Then your type specifier is wrong. You need to use the full name `name_of_class::prop`.